# Transformando input do usuario em label de botão

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Galera, estou tentando criar um botão que ao ser pressionado habilita um text field que devera pegar o input do usuário e trocar o label do botão para o input, porém quanto eu tentei reproduzir apenas consegui o seguinte resultado: [Video do Resultado](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=huO4CbHGhfc&list=UUqU6-elpaF02UOggzIOEgwg)

O meu ViewController:

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var iphoneSaveCharName: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var charOne: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var charTwo: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var charThree: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var charFour: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    var savedText: String!

//    func textFieldShouldReturn(textFieldInput: UITextField) -> Bool {
//        savedText = textFieldInput.text
//        textFieldInput.resignFirstResponder()
//        return false
//    }

    func textFieldEditCompleted(textFieldInput: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        savedText = textFieldInput.text
        textFieldInput.resignFirstResponder()
        return false
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textFieldInput: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        return textFieldEditCompleted(textFieldInput);
    }


    @IBAction func editText(sender: AnyObject) {
        if sender is UILongPressGestureRecognizer &&
            sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {

                textFieldInput.hidden = false

                let button = sender.view as UIButton


                if button.tag == 1 {
                    charOne.setTitle(savedText, forState: .Normal)
                } else if button.tag == 2{
                    charTwo.setTitle(savedText, forState: .Normal)
                } else if button.tag == 3{
                    charThree.setTitle(savedText, forState: .Normal)
                } else if button.tag == 4{
                    charFour.setTitle(savedText, forState: .Normal)
                }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu verifiquei o seu código e acho que a melhor abordagem seria guardar a referência do botão seleccionado. Tornei o código mais simples para perceber os passos.

O método `textFieldShouldReturn` faz parte do `UITextFieldDelegate` onde o `fieldInput` irá passar. Ao chamar o `resignFirstResponder()` irá forçar a passagem na acção `didEditingEnd`. Nesse momento actualiza o título do botão.

*Nota:* Por motivo de teste, terá que primeiro seleccionar um botão porque inicialmente não existe referência ao botão seleccionado.

#### Foi testado:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var fieldInput: UITextField! // Campo
    @IBOutlet weak var charOne: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var charTwo: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var charThree: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var charFour: UIButton!

    var selectedButton: UIButton!
    var savedText: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Atribuir delegate ao campo
        fieldInput.delegate = self;
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textFieldInput: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        if (textFieldInput == self.fieldInput) {
            // Guardar o texto do campo
            savedText = textFieldInput.text
        }
        // Finalizar a edição
        textFieldInput.resignFirstResponder()
        return false;
    }

    @IBAction func didEditingEnd(sender: AnyObject) {
        // Acção associada ao campo
        selectedButton.setTitle(savedText, forState: .Normal)
    }

    @IBAction func didTouchButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        // Acção associada a cada botão
        selectedButton = sender as UIButton
    }
}
```

---

### EDITADO para usar `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var fieldInput: UITextField! // Campo
    @IBOutlet weak var charOne: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var charTwo: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var charThree: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var charFour: UIButton!

    var selectedButton: UIButton!
    var savedText: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Atribuir delegate ao campo
        fieldInput.hidden = true
        fieldInput.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textFieldInput: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        if (textFieldInput == self.fieldInput) {
            // Guardar o texto do campo
            savedText = textFieldInput.text
        }
        // Finalizar a edição
        textFieldInput.resignFirstResponder()
        return false;
    }

    @IBAction func didEditingEnd(sender: AnyObject) {
        // Acção associada ao campo
        selectedButton.setTitle(savedText, forState: .Normal)
        fieldInput.hidden = true
    }

    //UILongPressGestureRecognizer associado a cada botão
    @IBAction func didLongPressButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        if sender is UILongPressGestureRecognizer &&
            sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
            if let button = sender.view as? UIButton {
                // Inicia alteração
                fieldInput.hidden = false
                // Acção associada a cada botão
                selectedButton = button
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Resultado final:

[image: resultado]

Comment: Mas então, o ponto é apenas editar quando usar um Long Press Gesture.

Comment: Só pretende alterar o título do botão se usar um Long Press Gesture na TextField, é isso?

Comment: Não no botão, você ira usar o Long Press no botão, a text field que estava invisível vai ficar visível, você coloca o titulo de botão desejado e ao apertar return no teclado ele salva no botão que você clicou

Comment: Já percebi. Tem 4x `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` associada a cada botão e o acção da `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` é sempre o mesmo método, certo?

Comment: Certo! É exatamente isso

Comment: Funcionou certinho, você é um gênio cara, obrigado!!!